# Can't use @Html.LabelFor and <strong> together

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working with ASP.Net MVC3 project and i used twitter bootstrap for my project. my problem is when i used  keyword to strong my labels it is not working properly. i tried like this

```
 <strong>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)</strong>
```

but it display same as before. i dunno the reason..

Comment: Like Spikeh... it's working for me. Maybe you've some CSS style that makes <strong> don't work. Can you put you label inside a div with style="font-weight:bold" to check if this is the problem?

Comment: Can we see the css stylesheet loaded with your page? It's most likeky a css issue.

Comment: What is the actual HTML output of this? I mean, when you do View Source in your browser, does it show the `<strong>`? And does `<strong>` work with plain text in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. :) Twitterbootstrap.css made that problem.

```
label, input, button, select, textarea {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 18px;
}
```

when i changed the font weight it works properly. thanx everybody...

Comment: It is not a good idea to change the Bootstrap itself, it is called Cascading Style Sheets, means: create your own CSS for that  (that will override Bootstrap) and leave Bootstrap as is.

Answer (score 1):

Works on my machine! :)

If you're having any issues with outputting Razor tags, wrap an extra set of parenthesis around it:

```
<strong>@(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author))</strong>
```

Comment: Spikeh:  is it problem of my machine?. i don't think so. i tried the way you mentioned above. but it is not working :(

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were getting an exception. It sounds like a styling issues instead - if you use a browser that's capable (like Google Chrome or Firefox), right click the label and click "Inspect Element" or similar. It will allow you to inspect the CSS that's been applied to the label element. Learn to use this tool, it's invaluable in debugging.